# The internalization hierarchy

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, internal-categories

For a complete category $\mathcal{C}$, we can consider the strict $2$-category ${\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C}$) of internal categories in $\mathcal{C}$. Similarly, for any continuous functor $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ between complete categories we can obtain a $2$-functor ${\sf Cat}(F):{\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C})\to{\sf Cat}(\mathcal{D})$, and for natural transformations between such functors we can obtain a $2$-natural transformation between the corresponding $2$-functors. This yields a '$2$-indexed category'

$${\sf Cat}:\mathfrak{Cat}_{complete}\to2-\mathfrak{Cat},$$

where $\mathfrak{Cat}_{complete}$ is the $2$-full subcategory of $\mathfrak{Cat}$ on complete categories and continuous functors. Similarly, in any $2$-complete $2$-category $\mathfrak{C}$ we can consider the strict $3$-category ${\sf 2-Cat}(\mathfrak{C})$ of internal $2$-categories in $\mathfrak{C}$. A natural question here is

> What conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ ensure that ${\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C})$ is $2$-complete? More generally, what 'niceness conditions' on $\mathcal{C}$ are inherited in some form by ${\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C})$? If $\mathcal{C}$ is a topos, is ${\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C})$ a $2$-topos in an appropriate sense?

Supposing there is some 'sufficiently nice' condition $\varphi$  on a category $\mathcal{C}$ such that ${\sf Cat}(\mathcal{C})$ directly inherits an appropriate higher form of $\varphi$, there is a canonical hierarchy of higher categories on top of each $\varphi$-category $\mathcal{C}$ given by

$$\mathcal{C}_0=\mathcal{C},$$ $$\mathcal{C}_{n+1}={\sf n-Cat}(\mathcal{C}_n),$$

and a corresponding hierarchy of indexed (higher) categories $${\sf n-Cat}:n-\mathfrak{Cat}_\varphi\to (n+1)-\mathfrak{Cat}_\varphi$$ taking the $n+1$-category of internal $n$-categories in a sufficiently nice $n$-category at each stage.

> Does this hierarchy (or a similar one) exist, and if so has it been studied anywhere?

Any pointers are appreciated.